# can i declare a postgres function that takes an array of any type?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Ie I need a function that can be called like this

```
select myfunc({1,'foo', true})
```

or

```
select myfunc({42.0,7, false, x'ff'})
```

to be 100% clear I actually want

```
select myfunc(array[col1,col2,col3])
```

where col1, col2, col3 are of different types. Maybe that makes a difference to the answers

Comment: I dont think it's about function (which can have anyarray ((which can be any array, but of one type)) - its about array can't be have a mix of types

Comment: Do you need the type information? Else you can fall back to `text` parameters (or `text[]`) - and cast input parameters in the call where necessary. Every type can be cast to `text`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - thats what I am currently doing but it smells a bit hacky

Answer (score 3):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC

> Each position (either argument or return value) declared as anyelement is allowed to have any specific actual data type, but in any given call **they must all be the same actual type**. Each position declared as anyarray can have any array data type, but similarly they must all be the same type.

function can accept `anyarray`, which effectively is array of values of any same type, not an array of any type mixed in one array...

what you probably look for instead would be something like:

```
so=# create function ae(i anyelement) returns anyelement as $$
begin
raise info '%',i::text; return i;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
CREATE FUNCTION
so=# create table pm100(f float,b bool, t bytea);
CREATE TABLE
so=# select ae((42.0, false, '\xff')::pm100);
INFO:  (42,f,"\\xff")
       ae
----------------
 (42,f,"\\xff")
(1 row)
```

Comment: doesnt that mean I have to declare a table for every possible combination of data types , thats simply not practical. I may as well decalre a function for each combination of types

Comment: yes - or create a type, not a table necessarily. and yes - I can't think from the top of the head any possible way to have a function that could accept anything without clearly defining that anything... effectively you can only postpone defining argument till you use function, not totally skip it.

Answer (score 3):

No, You cannot do it - @Vao Tsun reply is absolutely correct. PostgreSQL SQL language is pretty static - like C or Pascal. There are few dynamic features, but these features are limited.

Any query has two stages - planning and execution. And data types of any value must be known in planning time (dynamic queries and record type is a exception - but only locally in PLpgSQL). Because all types must be known before execution, PostgreSQL doesn't allow features that can hold type dynamic values - like polymorphic collections.

For constant values there can be workaround for your case. You can write variadic function with parameters of "any" type. It has sense only for constant values - types are known in planning time, and this functions can be implemented only in C language. For example, the `format` function is of this kind.

The necessity do some dynamic work is signal of "broken" design. "broken" from PostgreSQL perspective. Some patterns cannot be implemented in Postgres, and is better implement it outside or with different kind of software.

Update - 2023-09-23 - There is an possibility to use an jsonb array, where there is an possibility to mix different types (but only supported by json).